# How to get logs[data] generated by running application using Logstash Container

Tags: logstash, dockerfile

I am new to logstash and docker.

I am using logstash container to retrieve logs, generated by other application. As i am able to run container successful but i am not getting the output in my file "**finalOuput.log**" [ both the file **finalOuput.log & pipeline.conf** is in container]

1->
**My Docker File Content**:

```
FROM logstash

copy pipeline.conf /var/app/

copy finalOuput.log /var/app/

CMD ["-f", "/var/app/pipeline.conf"]
```

2-> **My pipeline.config file contains**

```
input {
  file {

    path => "/predix/Documents/workspace-sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/sendRohit/9aug/application-logs/application-log.log"
  }
}

filter {
 grok {
        match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"}
    }
}

output {

  file {
   path => "/finalOuput.log"
   codec => line { format => "custom format: %{message}"}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i am getting the data. Need to put the pipeline.conf in the root directory of container.

```
FROM logstash
run mkdir rvol
copy third-pipeline.conf /
copy outputdata.log /rvol/
copy inputData.log /rvol/
CMD ["-f", "/third-pipeline.conf"]
```

***And then fire the command: Below command is single command***

docker run -d --name=container_Name -v '/predix/Documents/rvol/inputData.log':'/rvol/inputData.log' -v '/predix/Documents/rvol/outputdata.log':'/rvol/outputdata.log' image_Name